# CREATE a table from a select query with LEAD/LAG

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, sql-function

This is the kind of table I have at hand:

```
 SELECT * FROM smf_table LIMIT 20;
   id    | trip_id | segment_id | segment_start_timestamp | timestamp  |     lat     |     lon     | travelmode 
---------+---------+------------+-------------------------+------------+-------------+-------------+------------
 5338113 |  533811 |          3 | 2016-04-01 00:47:16+01  | 1459467971 |  41.1523521 |  -8.6097233 |          0
 5338113 |  533811 |          3 | 2016-04-01 00:47:16+01  | 1459468020 |  41.1523518 |  -8.6097168 |          0
 5338113 |  533811 |          3 | 2016-04-01 00:47:16+01  | 1459468026 |  41.1524153 |  -8.6097054 |          0
 5338113 |  533811 |          3 | 2016-04-01 00:47:16+01  | 1459468031 |  41.1524057 |   -8.609701 |          0
 5338113 |  533811 |          3 | 2016-04-01 00:47:16+01  | 1459468036 |  41.1523647 |  -8.6097146 |          0
 5338113 |  533811 |          3 | 2016-04-01 00:47:16+01  | 1459468041 |  41.1525607 |  -8.6096725 |          0
 5338113 |  533811 |          3 | 2016-04-01 00:47:16+01  | 1459468046 |  41.1525077 |  -8.6096843 |          0
 5338113 |  533811 |          3 | 2016-04-01 00:47:16+01  | 1459468051 |  41.1524966 |  -8.6096833 |          0
 5338151 |  533815 |          1 | 2016-04-01 00:06:40+01  | 1459465282 | 41.14454009 | -8.56292593 |          3
 5338151 |  533815 |          1 | 2016-04-01 00:06:40+01  | 1459465412 |    41.14454 |  -8.5629259 |          3
 5338151 |  533815 |          1 | 2016-04-01 00:06:40+01  | 1459465600 |   41.163172 |  -8.5838214 |          3
```

THis is a large table containing over 100M rows. I want to create new table `temp_table` with filtered results from `smf_table` such that in the new table:

1. does not include rows where `travelmode` columns `IS NULL` (there are many)
2. does not include rows where `row2_timestamp - row1_timestamp = 0`.

So I thought of using a sub-query this way:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table
AS
WITH cte AS
(SELECT LEAD(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) 
  - LAG(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) 
FROM smf_table
) 
SELECT id,
  lat,
  lon,
  timestamp,
  travel mode
FROM smf_table
WHERE travelmode IS NOT NULL AND cte !=0;

ERROR:  relation "smf_table" does not exist
LINE 13: FROM smf_table
```

Comment: You can be getting errors from this query, but not that `smf_table` does not exist.  Are you sure you are running the two queries in the same database?

Comment: You probably wanted to select from the CTE, give that column an alias, and return the other columns too. What is `cte ! = 0` supposed to mean anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be getting the error that `smf_table` is not defined.  You might be getting other errors -- that `cte` is not defined, that the column in the CTE does not have name, that `travel` is not defined.

You need to select from the CTE to use the columns in it.  CTEs are like tables/views, not columns:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT s.*,
             LEAD(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) - LAG(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) as diff
      FROM smf_table s
     ) 
SELECT id lat, lon, timestamp, travelmode
FROM cte
WHERE travelmode IS NOT NULL AND diff <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to select required columns from your table and perform the operations and while selecting the final result, you have to select from cte instead of original table. You can also create the table directly as below without recursive query.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table as
    SELECT SELECT LEAD(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) 
  - LAG(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) as date_time , id,
  lat,
  lon,
  timestamp,
  travel mode
FROM smf_table
WHERE travelmode IS NOT NULL AND cte !=0;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot see your definition of `cte` in this query.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you subtracting `LAG()` from `LEAD()`?  Do you really mean to compare the following record to the preceding record while ignoring the current record?

Also, if `timestamp1 - timestamp2 = 0` then `timestamp1 = timestamp2`, so this can be solved with a `group by`.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table
AS
SELECT id,
       max(lat) as lat,
       max(lon) as lon,
       timestamp,
       max(travelmode) as travelmode
  FROM smf_table
 WHERE travelmode IS NOT NULL 
 GROUP by id, timestamp
HAVING count(*) = 1
```

Comment: By `timestamp1 - timestamp2 = 0`  I am doing a sanity check to make sure time difference between consecutive rows isn't zero.

Comment: @arilwan Comparing `lag()` to 'lead()` does not compare the current row to either its preceding or following row.  It compares the following row to the preceding row.